# Change encoding of xml when loading xml file via LoadXml() DXml object

Tags: c#, sql, .net, xml, sqlxml

I have some code in a code-behind page that is taking in an xml file. I am getting an error on my page due to a name having an accent in it, for example: José.

Is there any way I can change or dictate the encoding when loading this xml file into the function to, lets say, ISO-8859-1? I would like to add the the xml file is an sqlxml file. Therefore there is no header of which I can add encoding. So I am hoping to add encoding in the code-behind.

Here is a code snippet:

```
 LookUp x = new LookUp();
        x["DocId"] = DocId;
        x["hideAppr"] = hideAppr.ToString();
        string xml = summaryXml.GenXml(sql, "root", x.Text);
        DXml tran = new DXml();
        tran.LoadXml(xml);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the string xml from your code have XML header. Please verify what encoding does it have?

It should have something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

Comment: This is coming from an SqlXml file.